# Initializing another class inside class c++

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to make a new Node class and set its coordinates in my class called Colony (my run function is inside of the Colony class). It is segfaulting though. I have tried using new but it isn't working. What should be the fix here? Heres a snippet of the code:

```
class Node {
public:
  std::vector<double> coords;
  vector<Node> parent;
  vector<Node> childList;
  vector<Attract> closestAtts;
};

class Colony {
public:
  double D, dk, di;
  vector<Attract> attlist;
  vector<Node> nodelist;
  std::vector<vector<double> > attractors;
  std::vector<vector<double> > centroids;

void run() {
// Initializes a colony with starting point
    Node start; 
    start.coords[0] = 100.0; 
    start.coords[1] = 100.0; 
    start.coords[2] = 100.0; 
    nodelist.push_back(start);
}
```

Comment: Multiple parents? And as a value?

Comment: `start.coords[0]` the vector is empty, so you are not allowed to access *any* index. And adding elements to a vector is done with `push_back`

Comment: `start.coords = std::vector<double>(3, 100.0);`

Comment: or with `resize`

Comment: Ah I see. My vector is only 1D. Thank you

Comment: @destroyer806 The dimensions doesn't have anything to do with it. It's that's it's empty that is the problem. Note how you `push_back(start)` - just do the same with the `coords`. `start.coords.push_back(100.0);` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `run()` method, you are trying to assign the 0th, 1st and 2nd elements of the `start.coords` vector, but these have not yet been assigned. Instead you should `.push_back` these values, like so:

```
void run() {
// Initializes a colony with starting point
    Node start; 
    start.coords.push_back(100.0); 
    start.coords.push_back(100.0); 
    start.coords.push_back(100.0); 
    nodelist.push_back(start);
}
```